# Hibernate couldn't resolve property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi everyone I've found this problem, I'm quite new with Hibernate so I don't know why I got this error.

I have a class (Reservations) in java that communicates with the DB and one of the field is:

WrapperClient assignedClient;

where the idClient is a Foreign key to the Client Table.

Now I would like to find in my table Reservations all the rows of the same Client, so that I use this query, i'm sure there is something wrong in it:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("FROM WrapperReservation as wr where wr.idClient = :idCliente");
    query.setParameter("idClient", idClient);
```

where my idClient is a parameter passed through the function.

I'm sure that I'm missing something to manage the foreign keys, might you help me please?

Comment: is `idClient` declared in your WrapperReservation java class?

Comment: nope I have the object, but in the Db table I have the idClient.

Comment: So that wont work because you are doing a HQL which operates only in the properties of the object.

Comment: yeah but if I've a relation many to one between Reservation and Client, so that one client can have many reservations, on the Reservetions side I'll have an object clientAssigned. How can i get a list of all the reservations for that client?

Comment: Assuming that you have Client reference in your object.. you could do something like ` wr.client.id`... https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: You could map the idClient in WrapperReservation class with a formula that is a subquery

Answer (score 0):

A simple spelling mistake am seeing there :

```
session.createQuery("FROM WrapperReservation as wr where wr.idClient = :idCliente");
```

you have mentioned it as **idCliente** but while setting the parameter you are using **idClient**, see the last letter **e**

```
setParameter("idClient", idClient);
```

Comment: not I fixed this mistake. it's a problem that i don't have the field idClient in the table beacuse it's declared with hibernate as a JoinColumn